# Changing String Representation of JSON Serialized Foreign Key

Tags: python, ajax, django, json

I have a model, `Entry` with a `Foreign Key`, `author`, of type `User`:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
```

I periodically poll the server using AJAX and have a view that returns any new `Entry` objects in a response, serialized in JSON format. Here is the code:

```
def pollNewEntries(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=19)

        # Determine if there are any new posts since 19 seconds before current
        # time. AJAX polls server every 10 seconds. Stores ids of new posts and
        # checks those against any incoming posts, ignoring duplicates. 

        cutOff = timezone.now() - delta
        newEntries = Entry.objects.filter(pubDate__gt=cutOff)
        data = serializers.serialize('json', newEntries)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

This returns completely fine data for all of the rest of my `Entry` fields, but when I dynamically log/print/append `Entry.author` in my Javascript, it gives me the id field of the author. I've inspected the serialized object in the JS, and there are no additional fields in `author` to get.

Is there a way to change what part of `author` is represented in the serialized data? Basically, I want my view to return a JSON object that has `author.name` instead of `author.id` for the `author` field.

Comment: By default, it would serialize what is in the database table. And in the database, it would have store it as an integer field which has the id of the foreign key `author`

Comment: Your author should be located at newEntries.author.name.

Comment: try using the django-rest-framework http://django-rest-framework.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems if you [define a natural key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/):

```
from django.db import models

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, first_name, last_name):
        return self.get(name=first_name)

class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    birthdate = models.DateField()

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('name'),)
```

You'll be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: This is what I need, thanks. For completeness, though: you should have a `def natural_key(self)` function in the class you want to serialize that returns a tuple of whatever you want the natural key to be. Also, you need to set `use_natural_keys=True` when you call the `serialize` method. Finally, if you're using the `User` model (like I am), you don't need to do any of the Manager/custom method stuff. The natural key logic is already built in using the username as the natural key, so you just need to set `use_natural_keys=True` when you call `serialize()`. This is all in the above Django docs